# Node - fs.stat birthtimeMs and mtimeMs

Tags: node.js, fs

I have created an empty file on filesystem (NTFS) in Windows. I called `fs.stat` on it and realized that birthtimeMs and mtimeMs are equal.

This is good for my case, because I need to detect whether someone has not changed the file somehow in the meantime.

So on Windows NTFS I can do `birthdateMs === mTimeMs` and if it evaluates to true, I can say that file was not touched by anyone else.

The question is whether I can rely on this on Windows FAT and Mac filesystem too.

I know I can try it, but it's easier to ask whether some documentation refers to it or someone else has tried this before.

Comment: do u know if `birthtime` is reliably returned in UNIX (Linux/MacOS) environments?

Comment: @BugWhisperer: I can confirm it works on Windows as MacOS. I have not tried Linux.

Comment: k thanks!! @hippietrail

Comment: On MacOS it should just work with native FS's and I'd expect it to work with FAT and NTFS if the drivers are properly implemented. On Linux it depends on the versions of various layers as well as which FS. ext3 doesn't support birthtime but some other FSes do and support has been added to the OS and libc. The last missing pieces arrived in 2019. FS drivers for non native FSes may well not have it hooked up. In the worst case, it's been common over he years to confuse change time and creation time in plenty of code, sometimes on purpose.

Comment: It works on ubuntu 20.04 and macOS